# Acer Aspire 5750 broadband issue on ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, acer-aspire

I've recently purchased the Acer Aspire 5750. I've installed two OS(Windows 7 & Ubuntu 10.04 LTS). Till now, everything on Ubuntu is working fine except that I can't access my cable model broadband.

Upon opening the "Network connections" section, I see that its unable to detect any wired connection.

I've checked my ethernet jack and rest of the connection. All are perfectly connected but its still unable to detect my broadband. While on windows, broadband is working fine.

**Note:** ACER aspire 5750 uses Broadcom netlink 57785 gigabit ethernet PCIe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all download the network driver zip file for Linux from this location

[broadcom network driver downlod for linux](http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/netlink_k57.php)

after downloading you should extract the zip archive.

inside the folder you have extracted you can navigate to a folder named driver inside that folder you will be able to find

```
tg3-3.122g.tar.gz
tg3-3.122g-1.src.rpm
tg3_sup-3.122g-1.ISO.tar.gz
```

i'm going to use the `tg3-3.122g.tar.gz` file

open up a terminal window (alt+Ctrl+t)

navigate to the zip archive extraction folder

type `tar xzf tg3-3.122g.tar.gz`

then the tar file will be extracted to a folder named `tg3-3.122g`

from the terminal navigate inside that folder and type `make`

then login to the super user using `sudo su`

after login type `make install` in the terminal

that's it

then restart the machine,it will be working :)